# tensorflow operation for complex numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a dataset which contains complex numbers. And when I feed the data into the network, I got an error:

```
ValueError: An initializer for variable encoder/conv2d/kernel of <dtype: 'complex64'> is required
```

Here is some of the code in my network:

```
self.input_placeholder=tf.placeholder(tf.complex64,[None,self.train_data[0].shape[1],self.train_data[0].shape[2],self.train_data[0].shape[3]])
```

The error occurs in the convolution step before initialize all of the parameters:

```
layer=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs,64,[1,self.F],strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation=None)
```

Is there any solution?

Is there any support in tensorflow for complex numbers?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for complex initializers is not available yet.

There is an open issue describing a feature request here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17097

According to the discussion in that ticket, it seems that Keras already provides a way to do it. Maybe you can do something similar to that.